# E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'Pos' System.pas(28005)

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-xe3

```
    [dcc32 Error] psystr.pas(249): E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'Pos'
    System.pas(28005): Related method: function Pos(const string; const string; Integer):         Integer;
    System.pas(28165): Related method: function Pos(const WideString; const WideString;     Integer): Integer;
```

I'm getting the above error on the following function. How can I fix this? The code was given to me by another coder but I'm a complete amateur, so simple answers would be appreciated!

```
function ExplodeStr(const AString: WideString; AWordIndex: Integer; AChar: Char): WideString;
var
  Index, Counter: Integer;
begin
  Result  := Trim(AString);
  Counter := 0;
  Index   := Pos(AChar + AChar, Result);
  while Index > 0 do
  begin
    Delete(Result, Index, 1);
    Index := Pos(AChar + AChar, Result);
  end;
  Index := Pos(AChar, Result);
  while ((Counter < AWordIndex) and (Index > 0)) do
  begin
    Delete(Result, 1, Index);
    Index := Pos(AChar, Result);

    Counter := Counter + 1;
  end;
  if (Counter < AWordIndex) then
    Result := '';
  Index    := Pos(AChar, Result);
  if Index > 0 then
    Delete(Result, Index, MaxInt);
end;
```

Comment: Also, if possible. Could someone explain what this code does exactly?

Comment: Looks like an unfinished PHP like `explode` function to me: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: What exactly would you like to accomplish with this function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are overloaded versions of POS in System, you just need to tell the compiler which one he has to use e.g. by calling

```
Index := Pos(WideString(AChar + AChar), Result);
```

Comment: Thanks for this easy fix, it was starting to drive me nuts :-)